# Android selenium timeout

Tags: java, android, selenium

I added an assertion while the code cant find the button but Im gettting timeout exception.How can I solve this?

```
Boolean buton=getElement(By.className("android.widget.Button")).isDisplayed();          System.out.println("İzle butonlarının görülme durumu="+buton);
          Assert.assertTrue("İzle butonu ekranda görülmedi!!.",buton); 
         clickAndWaitForElement(By.className("android.widget.Button"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isDisplayed()

itself returns boolean value,modify it to

```
WebElement buton=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button"))
if(button.isDisplayed()) {  
        System.out.println("İzle butonlarının görülme durumu="+buton);
}
else{
          Assert.assertTrue("İzle butonu ekranda görülmedi!!.",buton); }
    ......
```

Comment: Yeah I had changed like this.it works:List<MobileElement>buton=driver.findElementById("com.digiturk.iq.mobil:id/productDetailContainer").findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button"));
      
     
 Assert.assertTrue("İzle butonu ekranda görülmedi!!.",buton.size()>0);